# Javascript function triggered on event - get target?

Tags: javascript, function, events, dom-events

I'm using the Youtube Javascript API, but it might not even be a question directly related to this API.

```
ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "foo");
```

If the state of the "ytplayer" changes, foo is exectued!

```
function foo() {
    //how to get "ytplayer" in here?
}
```

Is it possible to query what fired the `foo()` function inside of the `foo()` function?
Sounds weird and it's hard to explain.
Just imagine I have multiple ytplayer's like ytplayer1, ytplayer2, etc and every video fires the same `foo()` function once its state changes.

Is it possible to retrieve which ytplayer fired foo() function inside the foo() function?
Sorry, I can't explain it better! :)

edit:

Just so you get what I'm doing!

```
/*Control Youtube videos with swfobject*/
function onYouTubePlayerReady() {
    var $ytid = '',
        ytid = '';
    $('object[id^="ytplayer_"]').each(function() {
        $ytid = $(this).attr('id');
        ytid = document.getElementById($ytid);
        ytid.addEventListener("onStateChange", "(function(status){foo(status,"+$ytid+");})");
        ytid.unMute(); 
        ytid.setVolume(100);
    });
};

function foo( status, player ) {
    console.log(status);
    console.log(player);
    //var pl = player;
}
```

Comment: Blame google (or whoever authors are) for using `eval`, thats how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the only parameter available represents the status.

Since it appears that you pass a String that is evaluated, you may need to create a separate function for each:

```
function foo( status, player ) {
    // do something with status and player
}

ytplayer1.addEventListener("onStateChange", "foo1");
function foo1( status ) {
    foo( status, ytplayer1 );
}

ytplayer2.addEventListener("onStateChange", "foo2");
function foo2( status ) {
    foo( status, ytplayer2 );
}

ytplayer3.addEventListener("onStateChange", "foo3");
function foo3( status ) {
    foo( status, ytplayer3 );
}
```

or you could try passing an entire anonymous function string:

```
function foo( status, player ) {
    // do something with status and player
}

ytplayer1.addEventListener("onStateChange", "(function(status){foo(status,ytplayer1);})");

ytplayer2.addEventListener("onStateChange", "(function(status){foo(status,ytplayer2);})");

ytplayer3.addEventListener("onStateChange", "(function(status){foo(status,ytplayer3);})");
```

---

**EDIT:** *Generic example of creating unique functions in a namespace.

```
    // gets called by the namespaced functions
function foo( status, player ) {
    // do something with status and player
}

  // create some namespace
window.myNamespace = {};

  // this gets called to create a new function in the namespace,
  //     and call addEventListener, which references the proper function
function funcFactory( player, i ) {

        // create a new function in myNamespace
    window.myNamespace[ "foo" + i ] = function( status ) {
        foo( status, player );
    };
        // Add event listener that calls that function
    player.addEventListener( "onStateChange", "window.myNamespace.foo" + i );
}

   // your loop
for( var i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var playa = someGeneratedPlayer();
    funcFactory( playa, i );
}
```

Comment: thank you! However I cannot have a a seperate function for each player. Because all players are generated dynamically (I don't know the ytplayerNUMBER before). Your second anonymous function string sounds really good, however if i try that my foo function doesn't even get fired?

Comment: sorry, it does get fired. However if i console log inside of foo() like this...    console.log(status); console.log(player); the output is "5" and the entire swfobject "<object id="ytplayer"..> What does 5 mean?

Comment: @mathiregister: Could you please show the code that generates the players. If it's in a loop or a function, you should be able to reference whatever the player name is, and generate a unique function for it that references the player name.

Comment: @mathiregister: Regarding your last comment, that is just the console's representation of the DOM element. Does it show the same ID for each player?

Comment: And why is this not working: ytid.addEventListener("onStateChange", "(function(status){foo(status,"+ytid+");})"); Like i said I'm dynamically generating the ytplayer. I'm using javascript to store each player inside of ytid. So ytid holds ytplayer1 or ytplayer2 etc. Why can't i add this variable to the anonymous function call?

Comment: @mathiregister: You should be able to do that concatenation assuming `ytid` will give you a proper string. Check for typos.

Comment: console.log(status) shows always 5 (no video is playing on load) console.log(player) always represents the seperate ytplayer from ytplayer1 to ytplayerWHATEVER. The concatenation works, my mistake.

Comment: Thanks man, it feels like I'm really close now. console.log(player) always puts out the entire <object... How can I get the id of that object so I actually know which player fired the event

Comment: @mathiregister: I see. I didn't realize you were reusing a variable. I think what I'd do is generate a separate function for each one stored in a namespace so you're not cluttering the global namespace. In your loop, call a function, to which you send the player. Have that function add a new function to `window.myNamespace` that calls `foo()` sending the player you sent it. Does that make sense? I'll try to update my answer with a generic example in a minute.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question as well so you know what I'm actuall talking about. It might look a bit confusing. However what I'm trying to do. I have multiple youtube videos (all generated with PHP with a dynamic ID) on a page. My big aim is to make sure all videos are always unMuted() and play at 100% volume -> that works already! YEAH. The next and most important feature is... I don't want to have two videos playing at the same time. So if on video is already playing and i play the next one the other one should stop. That is my aim with the foo() function.

Comment: If I have the player that triggered the function and the status inside of that function I can run a loop for all videos on my page and call pauseVideo() on them. And then I call playVideo() on the one that fired the foo function. That's my really weird plan.

Comment: @mathiregister: I think I understand what you're doing. The example I added is probably a better approach than passing the full function string. That way you're not creating a new function each time theres a state change.

Comment: ...Since you're using an `.each()` loop, keep in mind that you can if you create a function inside of the loop, any local variables that are created inside the loop that the function references will not be overwritten (as long as they were declared with `var` inside the loop). As such, you could do something like my example, but without the separate `funcFactory`.

Comment: Thank you, i'll give it a try tomorrow. My head is exploding right now. ;)

Comment: @patrick dw. I can't thank you enough for your help, however i quite don't get what how your example would work. I'm not that much of a coder, sorry. I built an example so you can see how far I am right now. http://jsfiddle.net/yqy6d/3/

Comment: @mathiregister: You're very welcome. I updated your example with a solution similar to the one above, but got rid of the namespace to keep it simple. So the functions generated for each player will be in the global namespace. Give it a look. http://jsfiddle.net/yqy6d/4/

Comment: ...by the way, just wanted to point out that these lines of code were unnecessary: `var $ytid = $(this).attr('id'); var ytid = document.getElementById($ytid);` Since inside the `.each()` loop, `this` is already a reference to the current player, there's no need to get its ID, then re-fetch it by its ID. ;o)

Comment: wow, amazing! Thank you. However now it seems that I'm facing my biggest problem. :) I'm already trying all day long to solve this but puuuh - no idea! I guess now it should be possible to get what I'm actually aiming for. ONLY ONE VIDEO AT A TIME. If one video is already playing and a new one is started all others should be paused. pauseVideo() and playVideo() are the right methods for that :) However everytime I pause all videos onStateChange is obviously fired again and so i'm firing function inside of function,right? http://jsfiddle.net/yqy6d/5/ bottom-explanation...is that even true? :)

Comment: Some idea? I can't seem to get it working. Too difficult for me!

Comment: @mathiregister: Sorry, I didn't get a notification for your other comment. I'll have a look and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @mathiregister: Super easy fix (my favorite kind) :o). Exclude the `player` that received the event from the `.each()` loop by removing it from the matched set with `.not(player)`. As in `$('object[id^="ytplayer_"]').not(player).each(func....` http://jsfiddle.net/yqy6d/6/

Comment: @mathiregister: You're welcome. There's just one thing I want to note. You have this line in the function. `current.playVideo();` In that function `current` is a *string* representing the ID, so you're calling `playVideo` on a String. Since a String doesn't have a `playVideo` method, it should be undefined, which should give you a `undefined is not a function` error. I can't figure out why I don't get that error, but you may want to do `player.playVideo()` instead, or just leave that line off, since it doesn't seem necessary. Anyway, glad you've got it working. :o)

Comment: alright, sounds logical -changed it! Would it be difficult to add another feature? If a video is finished -> automatically play the next video on the page till all videos are played? Imagine I have 10 videos on the page and I play the first it should work like a playlist where automatically the next one starts after the other. Is that hard to do?

Comment: @mathiregister: I'm not familiar with all the options available. I guess it depends on what status report you get when a video reaches the end. If you get that status, you could perhaps check to see if any other videos are started or buffering, and if not, you could play the next one. Maybe tricky though if the same status message is given when a video comes to the end and when a video is simply paused. Not sure what the best approach would be.

Comment: There is a status (0) for ended. Right now it works when I the first video is ended, the second one starts playing. However the third one doesn't. If the status 0 is returned I create an array where I store all videos EXCEPT the current player. Then I simply play the first element in the arr. I thought the array gets overwritten every time and so it would work, but it doesn't. Any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/yqy6d/7/

Comment: @mathiregiester: Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/yqy6d/10/ I had to do a number of tweaks because the `onYouTubePlayerReady` runs once for each player, and not necessarily in the order defined in the document. So now it only runs after the last one is ready. I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: wow, didn't think it was that complicated. AMAZING, can't thank you enough! Is it actually possible to give you some of my reputation. I'd love to that. there is another Event (onError) that I could listen to. If I would add that listener as well, do I simply have to add it inside of `generateFunc()` like this `player.addEventListener("onError", fnName);`? Do I have to create a new `var` like `fnName2 = "through_error_" + idx;` for this? Should I actually just repeat the entire process inside of generateFunc() just for the onError event?

Answer (score 1):

**this** should contain the required object.

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't! `alert( this );` puts out [object DOMWindow] and not ytplayer!

Comment: This is probably what it should put out. Try calling some method or getting a property of ytplayer using **this**.[methodNameHere]

Comment: For example, try this: `alert(this.getVideoUrl());`